# Python - ¿Cómo crear mapa 2D con valores X, Y, Z en coordenadas polares?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema al representar datos en un mapa polar en 2 dimensiones con colores para representar la altura. Dados los valores X, Y y Z, me gustaria interpolar los datos y representarlos en un diagrama polar (ver figura adjunta).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
#read excel file
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\BrunoKISAB\Desktop\KISAB\Tools&Results\EH-Metrology\bamd04809.xlsx')

#load columns into Python lists
x_coor = df['X'][23:56].tolist()
y_coor = df['Y'][23:56].tolist()
lthk = df['Z'][23:56].tolist()
lwarp = df['Z'][56:89].tolist()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

radius = []
angle = []

for i,type in enumerate(lthk):
    x = x_coor[i]
    y = y_coor[i]
    rho = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    radius.append(rho)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    angle.append(phi)
    plt.scatter(phi,rho, marker=".", color='black')
    plt.text(phi, rho, round(type,2), fontsize=9)


plt.title('Thickness (um)')
ax.yaxis.grid(False)
ax.xaxis.grid(False)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
print(angle)

# polar plot
rbfi = Rbf(x_coor, y_coor, lthk)
ri, ti = np.mgrid[0:7.5:100j, 0:2*np.pi:100j]
zi = rbfi(ri*np.cos(ti), ri*np.sin(ti))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
#cax = ax.contour(ti, ri, zi, 50, linewidths=0.1, colors='k')
cax = ax.contourf(ti, ri, zi, 50, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
ax.set_rmax(7.5)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
#
plt.title('Thickness (um)')
ax.yaxis.grid(False)
ax.xaxis.grid(False)
ax.set_yticklabels([])

#plot results
plt.show()
```

Como se puede ver el grafico no se corresponde con los datos. Tambien tengo problemas con la barra de color, con un rango que no se corresponde con los minimos-maximos valores de Z.

Alguna idea de como resolver este problema?

Como detalle, tambien me gustaría quitar los ángulos que aparecen alredor del plot ya que no son necesarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]